# Time and date standards?

Tags: date, time, standards, datetime-format

What standard called for the use of HH:mm as the 24-hour clock whereas hh:mm is the 12-hour clock?

Likewise, I also often see dates noted as MM/dd/yyyy where MM is in caps to distinguish it from mm which indicates minutes.

Does anyone know what standard this nomenclature is based upon?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you refer to the CLDR project which has defined the LDML standard. LDML means: "Locale Data Markup Language" and is listed as "Unicode Technical Standard #35", see also the title of the linked document:

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table

However, you have not told exactly which language or library you use. Be aware of subtile differences. For example in Java, the old class `SimpleDateFormat` has exceptionally used the pattern symbol "u" as "Day number of week" while CLDR (and the newer class `DateTimeFormatter`) really interpretes "u" as "extended year (without era)".

By the way, I would never use "hh:mm" without "a" (as marker for am/pm in English speaking countries) or "B" for day periods (if your library supports it) because otherwise the 12-hour-clock is ambivalent.

Comment: CLDR is the project.  The standard is UTS #35 - "LDML".

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Thanks. I have edited the answer to give more precise details about the name of the standard.